# MYSQL + Change path + Update substring

Tags: mysql, path

I have a question, i have table 'file' with a column 'path' in my DB called Pics.
Each path is like "C:\my folder\pics\pic1.jpg" etc.......

How i do to change:

```
C:\my folder\pics\
```

to

```
C:\my NEW folder\NEW pics\
```

I try a select for the path folder without the filename like this :

```
SELECT substring(c1,1,locate(substring_index(c1,'/',-1),c1)-1) FROM t1
```

that give me "C:\my folder\pics\".
Now i need to update all the column path. What is the correct query. I try this but dont work.

```
update foto set path = 'z' where path = (SELECT substring(path,1,locate(substring_index(path,'\\',-1),path)-1))
```

Thanks for sharing

Comment: `replace(replace(c1, 'folder\', 'NEW folder\'), 'pics\', 'NEW pics\')`?

Comment: Yes and No. That is good in my exemple. But if you have a lot of subfolders before the pics, you need change all subfolders. That is why i use the subtring. But in VB i can use a Application.StartupPath & "\pics". I try and come back.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

```
update foto set path = REPLACE(path,(SELECT substring(path,1,locate(substring_index(path,'\\',-2),path)-1)),'" & TextBox2.Text & "'
```